# T-SQL - Assign field to NULL in a case statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Probably am going crazy, but I am trying to assign a field to `NULL` in a case statement, however, I get an error on the equals next to the `NULL` keyword

Here is the SQL:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN enq.IntField = 0 THEN enq.IntField = NULL ELSE enq.IntField END As IntField
FROM [Table]
```

Surely I am doing something stupid!!

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you trying to update a field with value?

Comment: In the case yes, but the case is wrapped in a SELECT Statament, so convert it first, then deal with it in the SELECT

Comment: can you paste your query here please?

Comment: SELECT CASE WHEN enq.IntField IS NULL THEN enq.IntField ELSE enq.IntField END As IntField
FROM [Table]

Comment: IS NULL and after then enq.IntField .we can't give enq.IntField = 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
CASE WHEN enq.IntField = 0 THEN NULL ELSE enq.IntField END
```

Comment: WOW, I literally wrote that in my query..worked.. then looked over to the other screen where this thread is opened and then I saw this answer. Knew it would be crazily simple. cheers